# Реальные проекты на Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

Здравствуйте,
не подскажите, есть ли реальные (завершенные) проекты, написанные на Java (IDE Eclipse)? И если я могу предложить свои услуги, то где мне искать единомышленников, или же заказчиков?

Answer (score 1):

А почему нет? о_О Конечно есть завершенные. Это в основном закрытые проекты для больших организаций, но есть и открытые проектики.
Искать:
1) Всемогущий гугл =)
2) Фриланс.
3) У Вас в городе по конторкам, которые занимаются разработкой на Java.

Comment: фриланс - не вариант. Серьёзные заказчики не ищут людей на фриланс-просторах, а аутсорсят обычно в конторы. Так что Java-разработчиков в фрилансе просто напросто нет.

Comment: Серьезные заказчики ищут обычно людей с опытом. По-моему фриланс как раз то место, где можно его набрать.
Опять таки смотря, где уважаемый barust67 проживает: если в большом городе, то можно сразу и в конторку устроится, а если как я - в маленьком, где за программирование на Java платят смешные деньги, то все таки стоит рассмотреть фриланс, как идею.

Comment: @Tanya а какая вообще платформа фриланса норм?

Answer (score 1):

[Github](https://github.com/)
[Google Code](http://code.google.com/)
Вам в помощь